# Why do I have this error : "argument type ByRef not compatible"?

Tags: excel, vba, byref

I'm knew to this language.
Okay so, I'm creating a VBA app which aims to manage the distribution of the deifferent courses in a school.

I have this error, which is really "weird" as I really don't understand why I have this even after few research on the web. It says "Argument type ByRef is not compatible". What is really strange with this error is that tt only appends when I define the type of my variable. But if I don't define the type, the it is empty and it makes the function obsolete. HHow do I fix that ?

```
Private Sub Ajouter(LBConcernee As MSForms.ListBox, Colonne As String, _
                    Quadrimestre As String, UEnseignement As String)
    ' This statement is "active" when the user wants to display the courses of the learning unit he chose (Uenseignement)
    If UEnseignement = Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row) Then
        [...]
    End IF
    ' If the variable is empty, it means that all the courses havve to be displayed and no verification on the learning unit is done
    If Uenseignement = ""
        [...]
    End If
End Sub
```

This process aims to filter the courses printed on screen by verifying the quadrimester and the Learning Unit of the course. But, with the "as string", I have an error, and without, *UEnseignement* is empty and it makes my filter completely obsolete as the first condition is never true.

The code and vars are in french (Belgian student) so feel free to ask any complementary infos.

Thanks.

EDIT :

Here is the code that call this sub :

```
Private Sub Remplir_ListBox(Section As String, ColonneDepart As String, _
                  ListBoxConcernee As MSForms.ListBox, Bloc As Integer, _
                   Optional Quadri As String, Optional UESelectionne, _
                   Optional OptionCompta As String)

    Dim CellulePrecedente, ValeurBloc As String
    While Range(ColonneDepart & ActiveCell.Row) <> ""
        ' On ne réécrit pas 2 fois le/la même cours/UE
        If CellulePrecedente <> Range(ColonneDepart & ActiveCell.Row) Then
            ' On ajoute les cours pour le/s bloc/s demandés
            If Bloc = 0 Then
                Call Ajouter(ListBoxConcernee, ColonneDepart, Quadri, UESelectionnee)
            [...]
            End If
        End If
        Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: By default, arguments or variables are passed `ByRef` meaning if you omit appending `ByRef` or `ByVal` in your arguments, it assumes to be `ByRef`. Have a read of [this page about passing variables ByRef and ByVal](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/byrefbyval.aspx) from Chip Pearson.

Comment: We really need to see how you are calling this Sub.  I think the "ByRef" part of the error message is not the root of the problem.

Comment: The majority of this code is not related to the problem, so comment out/remove it to reduce your problem to the smallest possible code which still has the same problem, then update your question to add that code: that will be easier to trouble-shoot.

Comment: What is the test on `UEnseignement` actually doing in `ajouter`? As far as I can see it makes no difference to the outcome? - both the If and Else blocks are the same....

Comment: The user can choose an UE, in eng it would be traduced by "Learning Unit". In each UE, there is differentt courses related to the theme of the UE. (E.G : for the UE "Maths" we could have the math course and python course for the analytics). And so, by having this variable containing the chosen UE, the app is able to display only the course of the UE by verifyting in the excel sheet that the UE selected and the UE read are the same.

Comment: Also, I shloud have commented that in my code (it will be done when you will be reading this), the fact that the blocks of the if...else are the same is because of the possible value of 'UEnseignement'. It's empty at the 1st launch of the program (so every courses are displayed) (else statement), and it is not and has as value the name  of a learning unit when the user filters the courses with a Learning unit (only the concerned courses are displayed (if statement)

Comment: I reviewed my code and changed the `else` in `if`. So if there is no chosen unit, all the courses are displayee and if one is chosen, only the matching ones are added.

Answer (score 1):

VBA passes arguments *ByRef* by default. Meaning, unless you specify *ByVal* all arguments will be passed *ByRef*.

There are two ways to pass parameter to a sub or function. (A) *ByVal* A new variable can be created for use in the sub or function. Initially it's just a copy of the original but if it's modified in the receiving procedure the original doesn't change. (B) *ByRef* Instead of making a copy, VBA just passes the address of the existing variable. Any changes the subordinate code makes to that variable will be available to the calling procedure. The value of that variable can be changed by the subordinate.

Not all kinds of variables can be passed *ByVal*. As a rule, VBA requires that all objects must be passed *ByRef*. So, if you try to pass a ListBox object *ByVal* VBA will complain. Perhaps, if you turn off Variable declaration, VBA won't bother you with such minor detail and simply refuse to work without explanation.

In your code all arguments are passed *ByRef* (by default), or so it seems. You can also define an argument to be passed *ByVal* by enclosing the call in parentheses, like `A = 15: MySub (A)`. We don't see your function call, so this is one possible source of error.

Presuming that this isn't the case I suggest you still focus on the ListBox. It might not be of the MSForm variety. For some reason VBA doesn't seem to be able to pass it *ByRef*.

The other parameters appear inconspicious. But perhaps there is a mixup in the calling procedure and you are unintentionally assigning the ListBox to one of the strings. In any case, you should look at the interaction between the sub and its caller. There is something wrong in passing the parameters.

Comment: "As a rule, VBA requires that all objects must be passed ByRef." - that's a bit misleading and perhaps could be worded better. An object variable is a reference, but that reference can be passed `ByRef` or `ByVal`, as noted in Chip Pearson's link mentioned above.

Comment: I will take a look to the link, meanwhile, I added the code that call my sub in the topic post. Thx

Answer (score 0):

`UESelectionne` is a Variant in the calling sub, but `Ajouter` expects a String for that argument.

Comment: I didn't see I forgot to put the type there. I changed it but I always have the same error, exactly the same one.